# MongoDB: StackOveflowError

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

User entity snippet:

```
data class User{
@DBRef
@JsonView(View.FULL_INFORMATION::class)
@JsonManagedReference
var Items:Set<Item> = setOf()
// and so on 
}
```

Item entity snippet:

```
    @JsonView(View.EVALUATION::class)
    @DBRef
    @JsonBackReference
    var user:User? = null
```

Comment entity snippet:

```
            @JsonView(View.EVALUATION::class)
    @DBRef
    @JsonManagedReference
    @JsonIdentityInfo(
            generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator::class,
                    property = "id")
    var owner:User? = null
```

So, when i send any request to the server, it fails with StackOverflowError. So, I figured out that the problem is in Comment entity snippet, if I remove/comment it, the program will work nicely. How to solve it?

Comment: so: in your user, you have a collection of items, in each item, you have a user, in which you can have a collection of items, in which you would have a user, in which ... do I get that right?

Comment: Ye, you are right

Comment: that is most likely your problem

Comment: ye, but idk how to solve it

Comment: have you tried not having a design like that?

Comment: yes, probably it`s design fault

Answer (score 0):

You have the annotations to deal with the backreferences in Jackson, but in Spring Data Mongo there is no equivalent.
My guess is that you should use manual references instead of `@DBRef` and write a custom converter.